# Filtering out the percent symbol

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and I have some code that prompts the user for a percentage then increases the value in cell A1 by that percentage. It works fine if someone plays by the rules and types an integer as a percentage. So, for example, if someone wanted the value to increase by 30%, they would type a 30 into the input box.

If someone adds a percent symbol in their response it wrecks the entire thing. How can I modify this code so it traps a percent symbol out and does the calculation based on the integer alone. Thank you.

```
Sub Box1()
    Dim myPercent As Integer
    myPercent = InputBox("How much of an increase?", "Input without the percent symbol")
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value * (1 + (myPercent * 0.01))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Replace` function to strip out any percent signs:

```
myPercent = Replace(InputBox("How much of an increase?", "Input without the percent symbol"), "%", "")
```

Or you can use the `Val` function to ignore everything after the first non-numeric character:

```
myPercent = Val(InputBox("How much of an increase?", "Input without the percent symbol"))
```

Comment: Clever approach indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Non-regex solution :)

```
Sub box()

Dim mypercent

mypercent = InputBox("How much of an increase")
If mypercent Like "*[0-9]" Then
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value * (1 + (myPercent * 0.01))
Else
    MsgBox "Not valid input. Enter whole numbers only"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try this code:

```
Dim myPercent
Do
    myPercent = InputBox("How much of an increase?", "Input without the percent symbol")
    If Not IsNumeric(myPercent) Then MsgBox "Wrong input! Try again.."
Loop Until IsNumeric(myPercent)
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value * (1 + (myPercent * 0.01))
```